# 2004 Yamaha Outboard 50HP vibrating around half throttle (2700-3100 RPM)

Tags: engine, vibration, yamaha, boat, four-stroke

I've recently bought a 2004 Yamaha outboard, specifically a F50 TLRC (four stroke 50HP) and it is generally in good condition, takes a couple key turns on startup but always starts, a little rough on the idle but generally sounds good, and at full throttle seems very happy. But at half throttle and a little above (2700-3100 RPM approximately) it has considerable vibration, it doesn't seem catastrophic but it is to the point where it doesn't seem wise to keep it at that vibration heavy RPM range.

I just replaced the spark plugs with no change except that it idles a little better. The old spark plugs had some carbon buildup on them but I don't know how long it had been since they were replaced. Oil and oil filter were changed just before I bought it two months ago. The previous owner wasn't sure when the problem began and said he never really noticed it but it has been that way since I got it.

Any ideas on what to inspect or try next in fixing this? Could it be related to the propeller, I'm not 100% sure it is the right size and pitch? Or maybe it isn't getting enough air at mid-throttle? I've also read some similar sounding issues that thought it could be when the carbs switch from low speed to high speed jets?

Comment: Maybe the prop needs balancing - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPxYBbqFDxE

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does the vibration occur regardless of whether it's in gear or not?

Comment: @Paulster2 I haven't run it up to that high of RPM out of gear, I was worried it wouldn't be good for the engine, but I assume it is okay?